# Android ambient light sensor and Service

Tags: android, service, sensors

I'm developing an application that start a service to execute an 
action when the ambient light changes. Here is the cinematic:

```
 Activity A
    On Start --> If Service S running, start Activity B 
    On Click --> Start Service S (not an IntentService) using starService. 
 Activity B 
    On Start --> Bind to Service S 
    On Click --> Stop Service S 
 Service S implements SensorEventListener 
    On Create --> Register to light sensor 
    On Sensor Changed --> Write a log 
    On Destroy --> Unregister to light sensor
```

My problem is: 
  When you launch the application and start the service, everything is 
fine. When the screen is turned off, Service S does not receive 
notifications from the light sensor anymore. When I turn the screen 
back on, no notifications are received either. If I destroy the 
Service and start it again within the same application session, 
notification are not received.

Documentation on sensor are not very helpful (or maybe I missed 
something). Can anyone help?

Comment: see my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31162516/why-onsensorchange-is-not-invoked-when-wearable-device-is-in-ambient-mode/38324733#38324733